# Laravel - Azure AD Authentication redirect me back to Login Page

Tags: laravel, azure

I am using Laravel-5.8 for User Azure AD Authentication. I installed this package:

```
composer require socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure
"socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure": "^3.0",
```

I also did the configuration. The regular Login from database is working perfecting, but I have issues with the Laravel microsoft-azure integration.

Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  use AuthenticatesUsers;
  protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectToProvider()
{
  return Socialite::with('azure')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
  $user = Socialite::with('azure')->user();
}
```

login.blade

```html
    <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class=" w3l-form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <div class="group">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
            <div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block" style="color: red">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class=" w3l-form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <div class="group">
                <i class="fas fa-unlock"></i>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <a href="{{ route('azure.login') }}" class="btn btn-primary"> Azure Login</a>
    </form>
```

route/web.php

```
Route::get('login/azure', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('azure.login');
Route::get('login/azure/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

config/services

```
'azure' => [
'client_id' => env('AZURE_KEY'),
'client_secret' => env('AZURE_SECRET'),
'redirect' => env('AZURE_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

.env

```
AZURE_KEY= something
AZURE_SECRET= something
AZURE_REDIRECT_URI= http://localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard
```

config/app

> \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,

For the Redirect URI, In Azure portal->App registrations->find your application->Authentication

I have

> http://localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard

When I clicked on Azure Login button, it redirected me back to Login page:

> http://localhost:8888/salesportal/login

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It could be that you have set the redirect URI to `http://localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard` but the redirect URI should be the callback route so `http://localhost:8888/salesportal/login/azure/callback`. You might also need to update this on the Azure AD side to "whitelist" that url as a valid callback. This callback is needed to complete the OAuth2 flow (your app -> azure -> callback -> check the user in your database -> login or fail -> your app dashboard).

Comment: @AlexBouma Where did you get azure in http://localhost:8888/salesportal/login/azure/callback

Comment: I figured that because of this route: `Route::get('login/azure/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');` you mentioned. That is where the Azure (redirect) callback should end up.

Comment: @AlexBouma Kindly, pardon me. I'm getting a bit confused. Let me explain:  When user clicks on the Azure Login, I want him to be redirected to http://localhost:8888/salesportal/dashboard.  Initial, when I set the url http://localhost:8888/login/microsoft/callback, I got page not found. What exactly I'm I missing?

Comment: Let me try to explain the flow on how it should go a bit more, maybe this clears the confusion :) You want users to login when they access `/dashboard` (I'll leave out the localhost/salesportal part). So you redirect to `/login` (or Laravel does) and there is a button to login with Azure AD which links to `/login/azure`. The users logs in with Azure/Microsoft and then Azure will redirect the user back to the callback url, which should be `/login/azure/callback` (taken from the routes you posted) in there `$user` should contain the user information from Azure you can use to log the user in.

Comment: To be extra clear, you still need to implement the actual logging in when the user ends up on `/login/azure/callback` by getting some unique ID from `$user` and finding the corresponding user in your own database and calling `auth()->login($yourDbUser)` and after that you can redirect to `/dashboard` and the user should be logged in.

Comment: @AlexBouma You are correct. Is it possible to help update the code in the post, so I can easily apply it?

Comment: Not without knowing a lot more about your app :) Check out what data you are getting back from Azure (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#retrieving-user-details) and work from there in your `handleProviderCallback` controller method to work towards getting a user from your own database (by email or stored Azure ID or something) and use `auth()->login($userFromYourDatabase)` and `return redirect()->route('dashboard')` to redirect the now authenticated user to the dashboard.

Comment: @AlexBouma Using        $user = Socialite::with('azure')->user();
        dd($user);  in handleProviderCallback,   I can now see the user detail as it is in Azure.  What I now have left is to use auth()->login($userFromYourDatabase)  and redirect()->route('dashboard')

Comment: @AlexBouma - Its nice having a chat with you. Thanks a lot. I can now login, but the issue is that when I entered on my email without password, it still logs me in. How do I make to validate the password with the one on the Azure AD

Comment: The idea of single sign-on using something like Azure AD is ofcourse that the user does not have to enter it's password (on your app). You trust whatever you get back from `Socialite::with('azure')->user();` as true. Azure AD validated it for you already.

Comment: You solved my problem. Thanks