# Azure SSO and Laravel login have issue with SAML

Tags: laravel, azure, single-sign-on

I have followed the solution explained in the [Azure SSO related question in the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331871)

After that i checked in the Portal Azure try testing from the portal itself but it keeps redirecting me to the login page only if doing it first time so its new to me though. am i missing something or i need to write login handler for my application to handle this as for now i have not created any handler for login because as per the description in the link it supposed to work .

I tried by having dd in the service provider that has been created but its not reflecting as i am confused and stuck here i am not getting where i need to write the logic where i need to handle users with type in this as for login now it is redirecting me to login route when i test it from azure portal.

Any guidance on this would be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you follow the Github documentation below for configuring the lavarel SAML SSO in Azure AD as it uses Lavarel package for SAML2 integration as a service provider itself. Also, as you have added the service provider in your case, it doesn’t need to if you are using v 5.5 and higher of Lavarel as it gets automatically registered. Its just for older versions that you need to add the service provider in ‘config/app.php’.

https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

•   Thus, once you do the above and publish the config files accordingly by executing the php commands, then you will need to modify the IDP settings in PHP app’s configuration and in here, please ensure that you are entering the ACS(Reply) URL and Identifier (Entity ID) from the Azure AD created application correctly. Also, ensure that the required SAML URLs and certificate keys are correctly entered in the environment variables required in the aad_idp_settings.php

Also, please check the actual routes in the metadata, by navigating to ‘http(s)://{laravel_url}/{idpName}/metadata’ as they must be reachable for your application to pass the authentication claims to AAD for get the authentication token and since, you are configuring SSO, please check the IDP metadata for ‘http(s)://{laravel_url}/single_sign_on/mytestidp1/metadata’ and finally please ensure that ‘RedirectIfAuthenticated.php’ is configured to redirect to ‘/routesPrefix/myIdp1/login’ and the same in '/Exceptions/Handler.php'

By following the above steps, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT

Thanks for brief explanation..

I have checked the documentation as well but some of things were confusing for me or due to mental blockage i didnt get it well.

For more clarity regarding provider that i was talking about service provider that handles the event of login as in the it is described the same in the link i mentioned in the question.

Now the issue is i am not able to dd the data in the Service provider that has been created which handles login event of SSO.

Comment: I am trying to test from portal azure just to check but it keeps redirecting me to login page of application and i also tried to dd in the service provider but still it redirecting me..

And in my case i have multiple user type to check before login so i am bit confused that do i need to overwrite the login of the package or it will work via the service provider that was asked to be created ..
Or do i miss anything..?

Comment: I would suggest you to please check the redirect URI configured in Azure AD regarding Lavarel application for SSO as after redirection only, the configured page in Lavarel application should be opened and displayed. Also, check the below link for configuring redirect URI for lavarel application in Azure AD : - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-azure-ad-authentication-redirect-me-back-to-login-page , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681283/laravel-azure-ad-authentication-redirect-me-back-to-login-page

Comment: i figured out myself in service provider with some debugging and finally that is working thanks for your help..